# Does the Twinned Spell metamagic option work with the Magic Missile spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, metamagic

If a sorcerer targets *magic missile* on one creature, can they use the Twinned Spell metamagic ability to also hit another creature with the same damage?

Comment: Related: [Can Eldritch Blast be Twinned?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62566)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) for the PHB states that:

> To be eligible for Twinned Spell, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at
>   the spell’s current level.

Since magic missile is capable of hitting multiple creatures, it cannot be twinned.

Comment: So no double-fireballs?  Awww.

Comment: @Zibbobz Fireballs don't target anyone, rather they do damage in an area of effect. AoE is balanced by the fact that you can't normally choose targets, so you hit EVERYONE in an area.

Comment: Wait hang on. Are you saying you can twin fireball? I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: @RobRose No, we're saying that you can't twin fireball.